# Clear Cloud Saved Passwords - Microsoft Edge

Tags: sqlite, passwords, microsoft-edge, group-policy, password-manager

We are migrating our users to a new 3rd-party Password Manager solution (Keeper Security).

As part of their documentation package, they included instructions for disabling the built-in Browser password manager. We successfully created a Configuration profile in MEM that disables autofill and new password saving.

Our concern is that we'd also like to be able to delete any existing stored passwords, both locally and in the cloud.

From reading this thread ...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1051573/delete-saved-passwords-in-edge-using-group-policy

...we learned that Microsoft stores the saved passwords in an encrypted SQLite database stored in appdata. When we delete the file, it regenerates after re-opening the browser.

The only way we were able to fully remove the passwords from the browser, was to perform a "Reset Sync" locally. This removed the passwords from edge://settings/passwords.

Questions:

1. Is there a Group Policy we can apply that would run the "Reset Sync" on all devices in a group?
2. Is there a way to know that stored passwords have been deleted from the cloud?
3. IS there a way to know that locally-saved passwords were deleted from the LoginData.sqlite file?

Answer (score 0):

Here're answers to your questions:

1. No, there's no such group policy. AFAIK, "Reset Sync" won't delete your passwords from the current device, but cloud passwords are deleted. So, you must have chosen not to resume sync on that device and you delete **Login Data** file after resetting sync. In this case, both local and cloud passwords are deleted.
2. Just like you've experienced, "when we delete the file, it regenerates after re-opening the browser". You can do the same to check whether passwords stored in the cloud have been deleted, but **make sure you have turned on sync**. If passwords have been deleted from the cloud, they won't appear after you re-open Edge. You can also check it by toggling the "Passwords" switch at **edge://settings/profiles/sync** to force password sync.
3. If you can't see any password at **edge://settings/passwords**, it means there's no locally-saved password left in **Login Data** file.

For reference, you can read [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-reset-data-in-cloud?source=recommendations#what-to-expect-during-and-after-a-data-reset).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The question now, is if there is some automated way to accomplish this task. When we disable autofill for our users, we would ideally want to make sure that no stored passwords are saved in the browser.

Comment: @JacobK, I got it, but AFAIK there's no other/better way to accomplish it, let alone "automated" one, and there's no such group policy to delete passwords or perform "reset sync". If it is not urgent, you can request this feature/policy by sending feedback in Edge (Alt+Shift+I) to the Dev Team.